# Download files with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to be able to download files on my Django website by clicking on a link. But even by following some tutorials it's not working. So first, I have a function that is generating files when I click on a button. This function is working fine, this is not the problem. Those files are being displayed on the page, and this is also working fine. The problem is about the downloading part. [The page that is displaying the file names as links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGGar.png)

This is the function that is rendering the page and that is returning a list with all the files in a directory. And then the other part of this function is supposed to let me download the files by clicking their link.

```
# views.py
def print_ip(request, filename=''):
    if request.method == "POST":
        get_ipfile(request)

    ip_files_list = os.listdir("mysite/ip_print_files/")

    if filename != '':
        filepath = "mysite/ip_print_files/" + filename
        path = open(filepath, 'rb')
        mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)
        response = HttpResponse(path, content_type=mime_type)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
        return response
    else:
        return render(request, "print_ip.html", {"files": ip_files_list})
```

And this is the HTML file of the page shown in the previous image. As you can see in the image above, the file names are being displayed correctly but I'm stuck for the part of being able to use the links.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Print Ip
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <h1>Print Ip</h1>
    {% for file in files %}
        <p><a href="{{ file }}">{{ file }}</a></p>
    {% endfor %}
    
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Print Ip Now">
    </form>
    

{% endblock %}
```

[This is the code from the tutorial I followed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4CcS.png)

Comment: first thing, the form does not provide the filename so the intended portion of the view (`if filename != ''`) never executes. In general, there is some redundancy between request type and a filename being provided. The second thing, imagine somebody providing a filename `../../../../../etc/passwd` - this is probably not how it should work. You might put the file into media dir and construct a link there instead

Comment: Also, `path` is probably not the best name for a variable holding file content

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I changed the != sign to == instead, but I'm wondering if their is a way to call a function in views.py from the html file? Something like {% 'download_file' 'filename' %}.

Comment: the condition should use `!=`, or even just a `if filename:`. You cannot call a view function from an html file - they live in different realms, html on the client and view on the server. The tutorial is flawed beyond repair, there is no simple fix to this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a shared scratchpad than an answer. I am going to delete it later.

From a previous discussion in comments: the files are dynamically generated (i.e., the content is different every time), but take no parameters.

Changes explained:

- before, a file was generated when the request type is POST and a file name is provided. This creates uncertainty for POST without a filename or filename with a GET request. Getting rid of the POST portion of it, `filename` is to be passed as a GET parameter. Also, semantics of HTTP request types is that POST is changing something on server
- requested file is validated to be among available filenames. This substantially reduces the surface of attack for potential exploits
- Since it's a GET request, no form is needed. Simple `<a href=..>` links will do.

```py
IP_FILES_PATH = "mysite/ip_print_files/"

def print_ip(request):
    filename = request.GET.get('filename')

    if not filename:
        return render(request, "print_ip.html", {"files": ip_files_list})

    # IMPORTANT: validate the input
    ip_files_list = os.listdir(IP_FILES_PATH)
    fpath = os.path.join(IP_FILES_PATH, filename)
    if filename not in ip_files_list or not os.path.isfile(fpath):
        raise Http404

    return HttpResponse(
        open(fpath, 'rb'), 
        content_type='text/plain',  # it's a download, mime type doesn't matter
        headers={
            'Content-Disposition': f"attachment; filename={filename}",
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'  # files are dynamic, prevent caching
        }
    )
```

The template:

```
## ...
{% block main %}
    <h1>Print Ip</h1>
    {% for file in files %}
        <p><a href="?filename={{ file }}" target="_blank"></a></p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Marat, I replaced my code by yours and I can now downlaod my files. You are saving my project. Thank you again and have a very nice day/night.

Answer (score 0):

First of all as @Marat pointed out your parameter `filename=''` is never changed in the function, therefor the block `if filename != '':` is never executed. Try `if filename == '':` instead.

Not sure if below is an answer to your question, but it shows how to download a file from the browser in Django.

To select a file in a template you can do this with `<input type="file" .../>`, note the `form` needs to have the statement `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

The file is then posted in the view with `request.FILES['file_name']`. Once you have it you can do whatever you want, in the example below I display the file in the same tab. Note in the example this only works for pdf documents.

A minimal example of file selection and display in the browser is below.

`view_select_file.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import FileResponse
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDictKeyError

def view_select_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            file_name = request.FILES['file_name']

        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            return render(request, "select_file_template.html")
            
        # do something with the file for example display in another tab
        return FileResponse(file_name, content_type='application/pdf',as_attachment=True)

    return render(request, "select_file_template.html")
```

`select_file_template.html`

```
<html>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="file_name" onchange="form.submit()"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not what I am trying to do. I tried your code and it's working fine but it's doing the opposite of what I want. I want to take a file from the server and download it on my computer.

Comment: Do I need to put a link in the HTML like : <a href="{% url 'download_view' %}> and then provide the filename to the download view so this new view will download the file he received as argument ?

Comment: @Marat, please advice, much appreciated.

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen Perhaps, a terminology issue. Established terms are: server is the machine running Django. Client - the machine(s) running a browser to access that website. Download - transfer files from server to client. Upload - transfer a file from client to server.

Comment: @Murat, thanks, am I correct to download a file from the server to client, only can be done from media files?

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen no, it can be in other ways too. Technically, there is little difference between opening a web page and downloading an html file; so, in a sense every response is a download. There is nothing preventing us from hand-crafting a response with proper MIME and headers to mimic any behavior, including a static files server. To make it a bit more user friendly, there's also a header for explicit downloads (`Content-Disposition: attachment; ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you all. So I think like you said @Bruno it's not possible to take file from the server and download it. Or if it's possible it's too complicated. Again, thank you all for your time.

I think we should close this  question.

Comment: it is possible, and is fairly simple, but requires a different approach

Comment: Ok so if you had to do it from scratch what will you do?

Comment: Are files generated dynamically? Do the change often? Is the list of possible files to get static? Does access have to be restricted (by user, by time, etc)?

Comment: To generate a file I have to click a button. So I think it's dynamic. The files are not changing but other can be generated. I don't understand what you mean by static, but they are all .txt files. And the files should only be acessed by me, so the normal users shouldn't acess them.

Comment: Ok, in this case you cannot use a standard file serving - you actually need a view. When clicking the button, do you enter any parameters? Is the downloaded file going to be different or the same if clicked on two different days?

Comment: No their is no sepecific parameters, it's just taking informations in the log I created and write them in a different file each time I clicked the button. So if the log didn't changed and I clicked the button again, their will be two identical files.